# What does "set the piece" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Greenmantle, by John Buchan, an American man was on a secret mission in Turkey during First World War:-

> I’ve got the cutest cypher ... No, it ain’t my invention. It’s your Government’s. Any one, babe, imbecile, or dotard, can carry my messages—you saw some of them today—but it takes some mind to **set the piece**, and it takes a lot of figuring at my end to work out the results.

What does this mean?

Comment: I believe "set the piece" means "apply the cipher to the original message to produce an encrypted version of the message"

Comment: Or possibly to configure a machine which assists in *de*crypting the messages:  the 'piece' could refer to a mechanized computational device

Comment: A search for cryptography in WWI turned up this result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad .  Maybe the author is referring to something like the One-time pad, where a lot of effort is put into constructing a complex cryptographic key.  This would also take considerable time and effort to decrypt, which would fit with "takes a lot of figuring at my end to work out the results"

Comment: From the same Wikipedia article: "Common secure methods for one-time pad delivery are ... or courier service" - the "anyone can carry my messages" in your quote might be referring to distributing the encryption keys via courier service

Comment: It's difficult to determine the specifics without knowing more of the context (I'm not an expert on cryptography or WW1, and haven't read that book).  But, it seems fairly clear that 'set the piece' refers in some way to encryption of a secret message, and that "your Government's [invention]" refers to the encryption technique he's using

Comment: If the OP is reading the book, and has understood all the preceding text, he should know whether there's an actual *device* being used to encrypt messages (as with [the Enigma machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine)). If so, ***set the piece*** probably means "set up / configure the device (piece) to use for the encryption". If not, it's more likely to mean "convert the message (piece) to encrypted form" (where ***set*** is used similar to ***set** [a piece of text] **to music***.

Comment: The short answer is there isn't enough information in the context to answer your question